# how to partition a series of numbers which maximizes the sum of products

Tags: math, optimization, discrete-mathematics

Given a set of n real numbers, we want to partition them which have the maximum sum of products, and every group has at most t numbers.
I think the problem is easy when all numbers are in range [0,1], we could let every single number in a unique group, then we could have the optimal solution. Similarly, when all numbers are in range [2,+∞),  things are easy too, we could sort these numbers from large to small, and pick t numbers each time, then we could just partition these numbers or let left numbers in a group , then we could get the optimal partition.
But things become a little bit tricky when numbers are in range [1,2]. For example, when we are facing 1.01, 1.01,1.01, the optimal solution is (1.01)(1.01)(1.01); when we are facing (assuming t=3) 1.99 , 1.99 ,1.99 ,the optimal solution is (1.99,1.99,1.99). That is, it could have many conditions depending on the different numbers. So i'm stuck in it for a moment.
And when numbers are just real numbers, things will become more diffcult.
I'll be grateful if anyone could give a direction on this problem~! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: You speak of _a set of n real numbers_, which means there would be no repetitions, but there are such in your examples, so you don't mean a set in the mathematical sense.

Comment: Sorry , i just meant a series of numbers .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when all numbers are in range [2,+∞), things are easy too, we could sort these numbers from large to small, and pick t numbers each time, then we could just partition these numbers or let left numbers in a group , then we could get the optimal partition.

I think sorting the numbers that way is a good approach also for smaller numbers, though we can't just *pick t numbers each time*, but rather have to figure out how many to put into the next product group in order to maximize the sum of products. It should suffice to find the position p within the next t numbers where the product of the numbers before p plus the sum of the numbers from p on is maximal. The following code should print the result for a reverse sorted list `numbers`:

```
i = 0
while i < len(numbers):
    p = max(range(1, t+1), key = lambda k: numpy.prod(numbers[i:i+k])+sum(numbers[i+k:i+t]))
    if i: print(" + ", end="")
    print(*numbers[i:i+p], sep="*", end="")
    i += p
print()
```

Note that I didn't consider negative numbers.

Comment: Thank you that much!! Your answer is correct and I'll try to give a mathmatical prove later!!  Thank you so much again!